# Wordpress - Website and Website/wp-admin Redirect to Index of/

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm uploading my website to a live site and I have an issue.  When I go to my IP (I haven't got the URL quite yet) it redirects me to the "index of /" page.

I also get it on my wp-admin page.  I've tried resetting my VM, making sure my Mysql is working, and checking my wp-config.php file, to no avail.

What may cause this issue?

IP: 35.227.21.18

Answer (score 1):

Try to slove your issue by doing any of the method  mentioned bellow..:

1.you need  change your site url in db(wp_options table) and also change all your loacl url to server url.

2.in local install duplicator plugin and run it it will take backup of your whole site and db and will create a zip file and an installer.php file. download both files and upload those on your server. run installer.php and follow the instructions. it will setup the wp site on server..

PS:- If you are not good in SQL I recommend to do it by plugin it is an easy way to move your site to live..

Comment: Your issue is sloved or not ??

Comment: what is your site_url in wp_options table?

Comment: try to change your url in all placed store in db to change to 35.227.21.18

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which solve your issue 
 1. Upload all WordPress Code in root of the IP/Domain
 2. Open database using phpmyadmin or MySQL benchmark and update wp_option site url to your ip/domain

Hope this may solve issue.
Thanks